# IntelliJ Java Configurations

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new learning Java in IntelliJ and I have a problem `edit configurations` which I don't know how to run my program `HelloWorld`. Some pictures are as below:
This is my code.

[image]

This is what presents after I click `Run`

[image]

It appears `Edit configurations`.

[image]

And then I don't know what should I do.

[image]

Comment: you need to (install and) specify an SDK for your project

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer (check-mark next to a question) if it answers your question; otherwise this question continues to show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have not set an SDK for your project, try [adding an SDK](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#jdk), if that doesn't work you have to [download and install](https://www.oracle.com/de/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) it first. And next time please add your code as text with the *"{ }"* tool not as a picture.

And to print something into the console you have to do it like this:

```
System.out.println("Hello World")
```

Comment: Thats nice to hear

Answer (score 0):

And also if you want to print to the terminal, the right way to do it is...

```
System.out.println("Text here")
```

And if you dont want to break the line when writing, you can do this.

```
System.out.print("Text here")
```

When using "" inside of an print method, it indicates that you want to print a String.